# Bouncing containers in Listview in flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, containers, gesturedetector

I know enable a button to bounce on tap but the problem i am facing is that i want to implement this on a listview containing containers but i am unable to do it.There are only questions regarding a single button like here https://pub.dev/packages/bouncing_widget but not for whole list of buttons/containers or so. I tried the above link package but it is also causing other issues like the list is not scrolling , and sometimes it is not working at all, Please help

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage()
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{
  AnimationController animationController;
  double _scale;
  @override
  void initState(){
    animationController=AnimationController(vsync: this,duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    lowerBound: 0.0,upperBound: 0.2);

    animationController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {

      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  void Ontapdown(TapDownDetails details){
    animationController.forward();
  }


  void Ontapup(TapUpDetails details){
    animationController.reverse();
  }

  bool lights=false;
  int count1=0;
  int count2=0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _scale =1-animationController.value;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Quickier"),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: 250,
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 5, 10),
        child: ListView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              children: <Widget>[
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: (){
                    Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder:
                    (context)=> camerapp()));
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 5, 0),
                    height: 100,
                      width: 200,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.grey[700],
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10),)

                      ),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(
                            Icons.camera_alt,
                            color: Colors.black,
                            size: 70,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                          Text(
                            "Camera",
                             style: TextStyle(
                               fontSize: 20.0,
                               color: Colors.black
                             ),
                          )
                        ],
                      )
                      ),
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: (){
                    setState(() {
                      if(count1%2==1){
                      lights=false;
                      Flashlight.lightOff();}
                      else{
                        lights=true;
                        Flashlight.lightOn();
                      }
                      count1+=1;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 5, 0),
                      height: 100,
                      width: 200,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0,horizontal: 20.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.teal[300],
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10),)
                      ),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(
                            Icons.highlight,
                            color: lights ? Colors.yellow.shade600 : Colors.black,
                            size: 70,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                          Text(
                            "Flashlight",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20.0,
                                color: Colors.black
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      )

                  ),
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: (){
                    HapticFeedback.lightImpact();
                    },
                  onTapDown: Ontapdown,
                  onTapUp: Ontapup,
                  child: Transform.scale(
                    scale: _scale,
                    child: Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 5, 0),
                        height: 100,
                        width: 200,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.teal[400],
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10),)
                        ),

                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                              Icon(
                                Icons.vibration,
                                color: Colors.black,
                                size: 70,
                              ),
                            SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                            Text(
                              "Vibration",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20.0,
                                  color: Colors.black
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        )

                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 5, 0),
                    height: 100,
                    width: 200,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.teal[500],
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10),)
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Icon(
                          Icons.settings,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          size: 70,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                        Text(
                          "Settings",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20.0,
                              color: Colors.black
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    )
                )
              ],
            ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

I have enable it on one container i.e. third the vibration one but when i apply ontapup and ontapdown on other's GestureDetectors very different things happen like if i click any one of the containers all are bouncing at the same time,type......

so, please tell me what I should do or if there is any other approach it will be helpful as I'm only a beginner.

Any other suggestions will be grateful too.

Comment: You'll have to create a separate animation controller for each widget your want to animate individually, then call controller.forward for each separate widget.

Comment: So,for that will i have to make init state method again and again or i can write details of all controllers in single init state?

Comment: Set all controllers in a single initState.